# Generics in python protocols - Covariance and Contravariance

Tags: python, generics, protocols, covariance, contravariance

after having read up on covariance and contravariance within  python I still find myself struggling to understand why an Invariant has  to be made a contravariant to be used within the context of a protocol  and I was hoping someone could further explain this concept to me. For  example.

Let's assume the following:

```
from typing import Literal, Protocol, TypeVar


MyType = Literal["literal_1"]

G = TypeVar("G")

class MyProtocol(
    Protocol[
        G
    ],
):
    @staticmethod
    def do_work(message: G):
        raise NotImplementedError


class CustomClass(
    MyProtocol[
        MyType
    ]
):
    @staticmethod
    def do_work(message: MyType):
        pass

literal_1: MyType = "literal_1"

CustomClass.do_work(literal_1)
```

This will yield The following error using pyright/mypy:

```
warning: Type variable "G" used in generic protocol "MyProtocol" should be contravariant (reportInvalidTypeVarUse)
```

Changing the function to return a Generic of the same type:

```
def do_work(message: G) -> G:
    raise NotImplementedError

@staticmethod
def do_work(message: MyType) -> Mytype:
    return message
```

This error disappears.

I have read multiple sources that will paraphrase the following:

The short explanation is that your approach breaks subtype transitivity; see this section of PEP 544 for more information.

https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0544/#overriding-inferred-variance-of-protocol-classes

I  have read the section and am still confused as to why this error is  being thrown for this particular example. Additionally I am confused as  to why covariance is needed when a return type is given for a function  defined in a protocol.

Answer (score 2):

Imagine if you had a `Base` and `Derived` class, and an object conforming to `MyProtocol[Base]`. You should be allowed to pass that object to a function expecting a `MyProtocol[Derived]`, since in that function, they would call `the_object.do_work(Derived())`, which is a valid thing to pass to the version that expects a `Base`, since `Derived` is a subclass of `Base`. Hence, the more generic `MyProtocol[Base]` is valid wherever the more specific `MyProtocol[Derived]` is, so the type parameter is contravariant (and should be designated as such).

Generally type parameters used as function parameters should be contravariant, since a function with more general parameter types is always callable with more specific parameter types.

---

On the other hand, type parameters in the return type are generally covariant, since a function returning `Base` is not generally usable where you need a function returning `Derived`, but the opposite is true: a function returning `Derived` can always be used where you need a function that returns `Base`.

Therefore, when you changed your signature to `def do_work(message: G) -> G:`, now you have `G` as both a parameter and a return type, so it should be both covariant and contravariant, but it also can't be either one; hence the default of invariant is correct.

Comment: "Imagine if you had a Base and Derived class, and an object conforming to MyProtocol[Base]. You should be allowed to pass that object to a function expecting a MyProtocol[Derived]" -- no, I would not expect that, I would expect it to error

Comment: I went on to explain why you should expect that. Since OP's `MyProtocol[G]` only has one method which takes `G` as a parameter, you SHOULD expect `MyProtocol[Base]` to work wherever a `MyProtocol[Derived]` is required.

Comment: If I have a method `def foo(self, x: Derived)` I have no expectation that somebody should be able to pass in a `Base`, because Derived is more specific. If I have a method `def foo(self, x: Base)` however then I do expect to be allowed to pass in `Derived`. However I definitely don't expect `Protocol[Base]` and `Protocol[Derived]` to have a default relationship. What if later I want to add: `def bar(self, x: Callable[[G], Any])`? I already promised users covariance.

Comment: I totally agree that you should be able to pass `Derived` to `foo(_: Base)` and not the other way around. What I'm arguing is that (as written) you should also be able to pass `MyProtocol[Base]` to `bar(_: MyProtocol[Derived])`, since the `do_work(self, _: Base)` inside the `MyProtocol[Base]` will work perfectly inside `bar`, since `bar` wants a `do_work(self, _: Derived)` and `do_work(self, _: Base)` is more general than that. As for what you promise users--I agree it's an API design decision and I'm not sure what the best practice is in this situation in Python (also re: avoiding the lint).